# Paperclip Rails 4 how to populate "Add file" field (allow multiple file upload) and delete an existing images with ajax JQuery when update the Post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Have some controller which givs an oportunity to upload 1 img. Post has many PostPics. 
The question is how to populate "Add file" field (allow multiple file upload) when create post and delete an existing images with ajax JQuery when update the Post?

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(3)
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
    @post.post_pics.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
    if @post.errors.empty?
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comments
    @comments = @comments.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(2)
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])


    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:text,:title, post_pics_attributes: [:photo])
end
  end
```